# Is it possible to list the names and types of fields in a record data type that derives Generic?

Tags: haskell, generics, type-systems, aeson

I know that for data types that derive Data.Data, [`constrFields`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-Data.html#v:constrFields) gives the list of field names. Looking at the GHC.Generics documentation, I think the same should be possible for `Generic` as well. (but miserably failed to figure out how to do it myself).

More specifically, I am looking for two things:

### List all record fields

... within a Haskell program. I knew that [aeson](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson) is capable of automatically inferring the JSON representation of any record data type that derives `Generic`, but reading its source code only confirmed that I'm clueless here. From what I can guess, aeson must be able to obtain all field names (as `String`s or `ByteString`s) from a record data type, as well as their types (that has the type of something like `TypeRep` in Data.Typeable, or an instance of `Eq`: anything that can be used for `case` block pattern matching would do).

I vaguely assume that creating a class and instances for `M1`, `:*:`, etc. is the way, but I couldn't make it to the type checker.

### Inspect a record selector

To get the record data type it belongs to, the record field name (as `String`), etc.

For example, given

```
data Record = Record
    { recordId :: Int32
    , recordName :: ByteString
    } deriving Generic
```

A function `magic` that is like

```
typeOf (Record {}) == typeOf (magic recordId)
```

Are these possible with `deriving Generic`, or do I have to resort to Template Haskell?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### List all record fields

This one is very much possible, and it's indeed done by recursing on the structure of `Rep`, using a class. The solution below works for single-constructor types and returns empty string names for fields without selectors:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.ByteString (ByteString)
import Data.Data
import Data.Int
import Data.Proxy
import GHC.Generics
import qualified Data.ByteString as B

data Record = Record { recordId :: Int32, recordName :: ByteString }
  deriving (Generic)

class Selectors rep where
  selectors :: Proxy rep -> [(String, TypeRep)]

instance Selectors f => Selectors (M1 D x f) where
  selectors _ = selectors (Proxy :: Proxy f)

instance Selectors f => Selectors (M1 C x f) where
  selectors _ = selectors (Proxy :: Proxy f)

instance (Selector s, Typeable t) => Selectors (M1 S s (K1 R t)) where
  selectors _ =
    [ ( selName (undefined :: M1 S s (K1 R t) ()) , typeOf (undefined :: t) ) ]

instance (Selectors a, Selectors b) => Selectors (a :*: b) where
  selectors _ = selectors (Proxy :: Proxy a) ++ selectors (Proxy :: Proxy b)

instance Selectors U1 where
  selectors _ = []
```

Now we can have:

```
selectors (Proxy :: Proxy (Rep Record))
-- [("recordId",Int32),("recordName",ByteString)]
```

The least obvious part here is `selName` and `Selector`: this class can be found in `GHC.Generics`, and it allows us to extract the selector names from the generated selector types. In the case of `Record`, the representation is

```
:kind! Rep Record
Rep Record :: * -> *
= D1
    Main.D1Record
    (C1
       Main.C1_0Record
       (S1 Main.S1_0_0Record (Rec0 Int32)
        :*: S1 Main.S1_0_1Record (Rec0 ByteString)))
```

and the selector types are `Main.S1_0_0Record` and `Main.S1_0_1Record`. We can only access these types by extracting them from the `Rep` type using classes or type families, because GHC doesn't export them. Anyway, `selName` gets us the selector name from any `M1` node with an `s` selector tag (it has a more general type `t s f a -> String` but that doesn't concern us here).

It's also possible to handle multiple constructors, and have `selectors` return `[[(String, TypeRep)]]`. In that case we would probably have two classes, one similar to the one above, used for extracting selectors from a given constructor, and another class for gathering the lists for constructors.

### Inspect a record selector

It's easy to get the record type from a function:

```
class Magic f where
  magic :: f -> TypeRep

instance Typeable a => Magic (a -> b) where
  magic _ = typeOf (undefined :: a)
```

Or statically:

```
type family Arg f where
   Arg (a -> b) = a
```

However, without TH we can't know whether a function is a legitimate selector or just a function with the right type; they're indistinguishable in Haskell. There is no way to inspect the name "recordId" in `magic recordId`.

---

**2019 update**: selector extraction with GHC 8.6.5 and typed `TypeRep`s. We modernize the solution a bit by getting rid of proxies in favor of type applications.

```
{-# language
  AllowAmbiguousTypes,
  DeriveGeneric,
  FlexibleContexts,
  FlexibleInstances,
  RankNTypes,
  TypeApplications,
  TypeInType
  #-}

import Type.Reflection
import GHC.Generics

class Selectors rep where
  selectors :: [(String, SomeTypeRep)]

instance Selectors f => Selectors (M1 D x f) where
  selectors = selectors @f

instance Selectors f => Selectors (M1 C x f) where
  selectors = selectors @f

instance (Selector s, Typeable t) => Selectors (M1 S s (K1 R t)) where
  selectors =
    [(selName (undefined :: M1 S s (K1 R t) ()) , SomeTypeRep (typeRep @t))]

instance (Selectors a, Selectors b) => Selectors (a :*: b) where
  selectors = selectors @a ++ selectors @b

instance Selectors U1 where
  selectors = []
```

Now the usage becomes `selectors @(Rep MyType)`.

Comment: Great! A quick idea is that since `recordId` is a selector that selects a field at a certain _index_, it could be possible to extract which index it is, and combine it with the `selectors` function you described to get the right name and type. Is it impossible? (Or can it be easily addressed with Template Haskell?)

Comment: @Minoru without TH we can only see the type of a function. That is not enough in any case. `(const 0 :: Record -> Int32)` has a right type but it's not a selector. As to TH, I guess we can quote a function name (e. g. `recordId) then look up where it was declared to see if it's a selector. But I'm not very familiar with TH, unfortunately.

Comment: @AndrásKovács This has helped me immensily. Could you make a version which works with Type.Reflection as well?

Comment: @JohnSmith I appended that to the answer