# Convert array of tuples into data record

Tags: haskell

I have list of tuples which I want to convert into data record. Tuple has type (Text, Text) where first item is key and second is a value.

```
data User = User 
  { 
    id :: Text
  , name :: Text 
  }

toUser :: [(Text, Text)] -> User
toUser kvs = ???
```

Is it possible in Haskell to set field name of data record by its string name, like you usually can do in C# or Java using Reflection?

Also I would like to avoid repetitive lookups through list for every field and populate data record iterating through list once, but not sure what is the best option to do so.

**EDIT**

Input list will be something like this `[("id","foo"),("name","bar")]`, so field names in `User` data record match to keys in the list.

Comment: You mean that the tuples contain `[("id","foo"),("name","bar")]`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem exactly

Comment: Is any order possible?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to traverse the list only once, I would insert the tuples into a [map](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.7.1/docs/Data-Map.html), then lookup each field name of the ADT in the map:

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)

data User = User
  {
    id   :: String
  , name :: String
  } deriving Show

toUser :: [(String, String)] -> User
toUser xs = User (find "id") (find "name")
  where
    m = Map.fromList xs
    find name = fromMaybe "" $ Map.lookup name m
```

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a way to simply add fields without having to add additional `find` statements as well, as one can do with C#'s reflection or template Haskell.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes, you are right, even though solution based on map is also OK, I would prefer to have something generic... You mentioned Template Haskell, I heard advises to avoid it, but if it does job...

Comment: yes, you'll need template haskell for that to basically generate all the `(find "x") (find "y")` code for you. If you can get away without it, I would recommend that though. Also, it may be a good thing having to choose different default values for the different fields (I simply used the empty string in my answer while ErikR used "?")

Answer (score 2):

@mb21's idea is very easy to implement:

```
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as M

toUser pairs = User idval nameval
    where m = M.fromList pairs
          idval = M.findWithDefault "?" "id" m
          nameval = M.findWithDefault "?" "name" m
```

But perhaps it's a better idea to write it as an update function?

```
updateUser :: User -> [(Text,Text)] -> User
updateUser (User i n) pairs = User idval nameval
    where m = M.fromList pairs
          idval = M.findWithDefault  i m
          nameval = M.findWithDefault v "name" m
```

Comment: Is there way to use `Generic` package to get field names?

Comment: And it has already been asked! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27815489/is-it-possible-to-list-the-names-and-types-of-fields-in-a-record-data-type-that